# what is the meaning of "~n" before a package name in apt package manager?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, regular-expression

I was having too much trouble with the nvidia-driver on my linux mint machine so I decided to completely uninstall the nvidia driver. To do that I started searching some mint forums and I found this command.

```
sudo apt purge ~nnvidia
```

So what is the purpose of this "~n"?

also on some other sites i found this simple regex

```
sudo apt purge '*nvidia*'
```

As far I understand this one just selects the packages which have "nvidia" in them.

But the `~nnvidia` command selects some extra packages than the `*nvidia*`.

here are packages selected by `~nnvidia`:

```
  libnvidia-cfg1-390* libnvidia-common-390* libnvidia-compute-390* libnvidia-compute-390:i386*
  libnvidia-compute-460* libnvidia-decode-390* libnvidia-decode-390:i386* libnvidia-encode-390*
  libnvidia-encode-390:i386* libnvidia-fbc1-390* libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386* libnvidia-gl-390*
  libnvidia-gl-390:i386* libnvidia-ifr1-390* libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386* nvidia-compute-utils-390*
  nvidia-compute-utils-460* nvidia-dkms-390* nvidia-dkms-460* nvidia-driver-390* nvidia-kernel-common-390*
  nvidia-kernel-common-460* nvidia-kernel-source-390* nvidia-prime* nvidia-prime-applet* nvidia-settings*
  nvidia-utils-390* xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390*
```

packages selected by `*nvidia*`

```
  libnvidia-cfg1-390* libnvidia-common-390* libnvidia-compute-390* libnvidia-compute-460*
  libnvidia-decode-390* libnvidia-encode-390* libnvidia-fbc1-390* libnvidia-gl-390* libnvidia-gl-390:i386*
  libnvidia-ifr1-390* libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386* nvidia-compute-utils-390* nvidia-compute-utils-460*
  nvidia-dkms-390* nvidia-dkms-460* nvidia-driver-390* nvidia-kernel-common-390* nvidia-kernel-common-460*
  nvidia-kernel-source-390* nvidia-prime* nvidia-prime-applet* nvidia-settings* nvidia-utils-390*
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390*
```

so why these `:i386` packages are not included in the `*nvidia*`?

Comment: It's weird but do you have user named `nnvidia`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk no that would have been wierd :)

Answer (score 3):

The `~n` tells `apt` that you're trying to match the name as a regular-expression as opposed to a simple string comparison.

A regular-expression of `nvidia` means match anything that has the substring `nvidia` within it, as opposed to matching the complete string `nvidia`.

Therefore you get a far longer list.

More details [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-patterns.7.en.html).  Note that this feature is only available with `apt` from version 1.9.6 onwards.  Earlier versions automatically search by regular expressions if a basic string comparison doesn't match.

Comment: I just realized the "\*nvidia\*" is not even a valid regular expression. the * in the "\*nvidia\*" is not as in regular expression but a "wildcard" thing.So tell me if I got it right...Putting ~n just tells the apt that next thing is a regular expression. if we do not put that then it is treated as a simple string. Now that simple string can be made special by using wildcards. So a "\*nvidia\*" will select any package containing nvidia name in it. Then why they are not giving same results?

Comment: I don't have `nvidia` so can't really comment.   I tried a test uninstall of python using both `~npython` and `*python*` and got 101 files to be removed in both cases.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. I guess due to some weird reason the \*nvidia\* is not giving out the i386 versions of some packages.